# Java - execute method only once

Tags: java, recursion, infinite-loop

I have a simple problem:

```
Class A{

    B b;

    public void doSth{ 
         //This method should execute only once
         b.modify(); //calls doSth() again...
    }
}
```

As the program runs, an instance of A is passed to B, and B calls doSth (as a callback for instance). `b.modify` makes B to call `A.doSth()` again, which will infinite sequence of calls. What I want to achieve is this: I want to execute doSth() once, modify B, then upon next execution somehow stop the chain of inifinite calls and do not execute `b.modify`.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a flag that you set false the first time?

Comment: You could achieve that e.g. with an additional parameter to the method, but isn't this more a design question? What are you trying to model?

Comment: As per coding guidelines, this will be considered as a circular dependency and should be avoided. Since you are asking, we could maintain a static boolean in A class which controls the execution of doSth in class A for only once.

Comment: I agree with @twoflower - obviously from the answers, you can use a flag, but it feels like a design smell.  What are you actually doing?

Comment: I register listener on the JFreeChart, and the listener modifies one of the series, causing ChartChangeEvent to be raised again and calling my listener...

Comment: I register it using addChangeListener

Comment: basically when you modify chart, you know you will received event, so easiest way (but crappy design) it will be put some value ie : boolean  ignoreChange, and if you will change chart, you will set is as true, in your listener if you have this as true, just ignore all actions and set value to false

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a state flag to your class:

```
Class A {

    B b;
    private volatile boolean called;

    public synchronized void doSth { 
         if (called) return;
         called = true;
         b.modify();
    }
}
```

Use `volatile` if multiple threads are in play.

Comment: Perhaps you want to clear the flag as well otherwise `doSth` will never be called again. Otherwise you could just clear `b = null;` and check for null.

Comment: Shouldn't use this example in real concurrent cases. You can get both threads run "if" and both will pass to the next line.
It's better to use CAS here, something like:
<pre>
private final AtomicBoolean called = new AtomicBoolean();
and then
if (!called.compareAndSet(false, true)) return;
</pre>

or if you prefer to use "plain and pure" style, use double checking with synchronized:
<pre>
boolean mayPass = false;
if (!called) {
  synchronized(this) { // or some external object
    if (!called) {
      called = true;
      mayPass = true;
    }
  }
}
if (!mayPass) return;
...
</pre>

Comment: @dchekmarev you're right! I can't believe I omitted synchronization... (made method synchronized - good enough for the example)

Answer (score 2):

You can have a boolean field and set it true the first time you call the method.

```
Class A{
    boolean isModified = false;
    B b;

    public void doSth{ 
        if(!isModified) {
            this.isModified = true;
            b.modify();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd try to find a solution that doesn't involve circular dependencies. Do A and B really have to reference eachother? On a higher level, what are you trying to achieve? Could you post some client code using A and B objects?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `boolean alreadyExecuted` to class A and modify the implementation of doSmth() to

```
 public void doSth{ 
     if(!alreadyExecuted){
         alreadyExecuted = true; 
         b.modify(); 

     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this as a Hack...

Use `boolean` variable

```
Class A{

    B b;
    public isOk = true;

    public void doSth{ 

        if (isOk){

         b.modify(); 
         isOk = false;

        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should change design to not call those method recursively, or if you cant just add parameter to your doSth method

```
doSth(boolean modify)
 {
  if (modify) 
  {
    b.modify();
  }
  ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a fix for "best" example, coz noone should really use it in concurrent/multithreading cases. You can get both threads run "if" and both will pass to the next line.
It's better to use CAS here, something like:

```
private final AtomicBoolean called = new AtomicBoolean();

and then

if (!called.compareAndSet(false, true)) return;
```

or if you prefer to use "plain and pure" style, use double checking with synchronized:

```
private volatile boolean called;

and then

boolean mayPass = false;
if (!called) {
  synchronized(this) { // or some external object
    if (!called) {
      called = true;
      mayPass = true;
    }
  }
}
if (!mayPass) return;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your job in the constructor

```
Class A{

   B b;

   A(){
       //This should execute only once
       b.modify(); //calls doSth() again...
   }

}
```